# How do I get rigid body activation to propagate through a set of rigid bodies?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have around 3K LEGO bricks tied together and I made them all rigid bodies (active RB). Is there a way to control the way they "activate" and start the simulation?

For example, if those bricks are hit by another object they all start to move at the same time and I don't want this. I would like to see the simulation propagate from the collision point to all the rest of the model.

Comment: @Leander They're not asking how to set a property on multiple rigid bodies, they're asking how to get an object to 'activate' as a force passes through a group of objects.